# Choose 3 cards from a deck, if last two are spades what is the chance of first card being a spade?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I'm stuck on this problem, and need some explanation if possible :

> From 52 cards we take 1, after that we take 2 more, both of which are spades. What are the odds that first card is also a spade?

In particular, I'm not sure how to set up my Hypotheses/Evidence. I have a feeling that there might be some case branching or something but I'm unsure on how to set up the whole problem.

Comment: **Hint:** Relate this problem with the problem where we take one card from a deck of $50$ which has two spades missing.  What is the probability of that one card being a spade?  (How many spades are still available in the deck out of how many cards?)  Why will the answer to this related problem be the same as the answer to the problem you mention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: This question could be asked in a very strange way that might actually be easier to understand: Knowing that the NEXT TWO cards MUST be spades, what are the odds that this first card is a spade?

I should add that JMoravitz's comment is really excellent.

Comment: Oh... I get it. So, since we know that two spades are already taken/reserved that leaves us with 2 less spades to choose from.

Comment: There you go! It is always helpful to try to reword problems like this, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities of drawing the three cards are the same in any order, so imagine drawing the two known spades first.  What is the chance the third card is a spade?

Answer (score 1):

The question is to ask the conditional prob
$$
P(\text{1st card is spade|2nd and 3rd cards are spades})
$$
Let's break it down like
$$
\frac{P(\text{1st card is spade AND 2nd and 3rd cards are spades})}{P(\text{2nd and 3rd cards are spades})} = \frac{P(\text{1st, 2nd and 3rd cards are spades})}{P(\text{2nd and 3rd cards are spades})}
$$

$$
P(\text{1st, 2nd and 3rd cards are spades}) = \frac{13}{52}\frac{12}{51}\frac{11}{50}
$$

$$
P(\text{2nd and 3rd cards are spades}) = P(\text{1st, 2nd and 3rd cards are spades}) + P(\text{1st is NOT spade, 2nd and 3rd cards are spades}) = \frac{13}{52}\frac{12}{51}\frac{11}{50} + \frac{39}{52}\frac{13}{51}\frac{12}{50}
$$
Plug in all numbers back to the question I got
$$
\frac{11}{50}
$$

Comment: I like this answer in addition to the others, because together they provide the intuition (the other answers) and the rigorous mathematics (this answer). Well done.

Comment: @TheCount Thanks for your support!